# netem delay is not causing an increase in latency

Tags: linux

I am trying to emulate increased latency in my development environment using netem:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 10000ms
```

However, this delay is not occurring. These are my ping statistics before the above command (10 pings):

```
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9027ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.023/0.034/0.045/0.004 ms
```

And these are the ping statics after the above command (10 pings):

```
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 9005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.025/0.031/0.037/0.029 ms
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you ping from the same machine as netem, or through it?

Comment: I am pinging from the same machine, since I am running the server and testing in different browsers from the machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try setting the latency on the `lo` device instead. By default netem sets a queue impairment on the egress queue. This is used when routing or bridging through the box. You won't see it on the same machine.